# Outsourcing map menu

Tags: android, google-maps, design-patterns, menu, mapactivity

I am using the android pie radial menu widget (http://code.google.com/p/radial-menu-widget/downloads/list - The v2 version) and to make the code more elegent I outsourced the menu code for a different class, problem is I am using the menu item on a google map and upon clicking I want to add overlays to the map according to the user selection on the menu, since the menu is a standalone class i'm sending the constructor the map activity context and inside the menu on the onClickListener i'm activating a static method on the map (a method that should place objects on the map according to id number) - it does not work though and keeps on crashing (once the menu try to access the static method on the mapavtivity it crashes right away). does anyone have an idea how do i make it work? =\
p.s 
I know that basically i made the map activity and the map pie radial menu tightly coupled I just didnt thought of any better way..will appriciate any kind of help/suggestion